# How to use certificates from a java PKCS#12 keystore for encrypting and decrypting files?

Tags: java, cryptography, pkcs#12

Can anyone explain how to encrypt and decrypt files using certificates stored in a java 'PKCS#12` keystore?

Comment: PKCS#12 is not an encryption algorithm so your question makes no sense.

Comment: This question (and its answer) was very helpful for me. With the current text and subject line, it should be reopened

Answer (score 25):

As mention Eugene Mayevski, your question is wrong and cannot be answered in its original form. But I'll try to clarify it for you a bit. [PKCS#12](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_12) - cryptographic format is *for storing* cerificates and private keys. When you encrypt or decrypt data, you use cipher implementation and *content* of `PKCS#12` container.

Java has build-in support for work with PKCS#12 keystores, work with this containers doesn't much differ than standart JKS keystore.

For example, code to load JKS keystore

```
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
store.load(is, password.toCharArray());
```

and code to load PKCS#12 keystore

```
KeyStore store = KeyStore.getInstance("PKCS12");
store.load(is, password.toCharArray());
```

After that you have unlimited accsess to keystore content. You can get certificates and keys, stored in keystore, without that strange actions with import/export in Firefox.

```
Key key = store.getKey("alias_for_key", password.toCharArray());
```

Next thing, when you have keys and certificates, is encryption. For encryption. you need instance of Cipher class.

```
Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(key.getAlgorithm());
c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
```

Cipher ready to encrypt. If encryption data is relativily small, you can use `update()` method, other way is to create `CipherOutputStream`.

To decrypt, simply init cipher with different mode and, depends of encryption algorithm, key. For symmetric algorithm key will the same, for asymmetric algorithm for encryption uses public key, and for decryption private key.

In this [article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptography) you can learn more about cryptography.

Comment: I think PKCS#12 based key store use strings containing numbers as alias, you cannot just use any alias (where would you store the alias in the PKCS#12 key store?). But I must admit I'm not 100% sure of this.

Comment: PKCS12 offers stronger cryptographic algorithms than JKS. Switching to PKCS12 improves keystore integrity and confidentiality.  http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/229

Answer (score 7):

[This blog post should explain it to you perfectly](http://coenos.com/blog/?p=257).

> Using the PKCS12 encryption with PEM files.
>
> To get this running you first need a Java Keystore in PFX (Personal
>   File Exchange) format.

**Keytool command:**

```
 keytool -genkeypair -alias mykeystore -keypass lala -keystore
 mykeystore.pfx -storepass lala -validity 10000 -keyalg RSA -keysize
 2048 -storetype pkcs12
```

This will generate the mykeystore.pfx file. This file can be imported
as a Certificate in Firefox.

**Import** - Open Firefox – Tools – Options – Advanced – View Certificates – You Certificates – Import – Select PFX file – Import it.

**Export** - Select the Certificate – View – Details – Export it to X.509 PEM). (you can also export to DER)

**1. The Private Key**

First we need to extract the Private Key from the PFX file.

**2. The Public Key**

Secondly you will need to encrypt a file using the public key. But first you need the public key.

**3. Encryption with the Public Key**

Now you have the Public Key you can encrypt a File.

**4. Decryption with the Private Key**

So now the file is encrypted it can be sent/stored for the receiving party to…well…receive it and decrypt it. To decrypt it we need the Private Key and luckily that was saved/stored in the private.pem file

**5. Encryption/Decryption with AES keys**

Another way to encrypt/decrypt stuff is via an AES 256 bits key. The key will be generated randomly per file and written to the file system. Then this AES key can be encrypted using the above RSA mechanism. This will improve the performance of encryption for large files.

Source - http://coenos.com/blog/?p=257

Comment: Thanks for immediate reply. How are the ".pfx" and PEM files used?

Comment: @Sasha pfx files are usually files containing an encrypted private key and are typically password protected, PEM are basically files that contains a private key, which is useful in case you want to update the extension at a later point

Comment: The title makes no sense: PKCS#12 is a format for secure storage of keys, not for encryption of anything.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp - People would be thankful to the person who helps / answer / guide them in right direction rather finding faults or correcting the question. Hope you will put your efforts in correct place for others. Thanks.

Comment: @Daniel because the question doesn't make sense in the first place.

Comment: @Daniel if you are a clairvoyant and understand what the user asked about, you could *properly* edit the question to bring some sense to question. Your edition (eg. adding "algorithm" to the question title) didn't make sense.

Comment: @EugeneMayevski'EldoSCorp Why didn't you just re-edit it if it's upset you so much?

Comment: @Daniel cause it must be deleted - the original question is void and any edition would create a new question. Right now users will just vote to close the question and it will be closed within a couple of hours.

Comment: ...Or you could just take out the word 'algorithm' wherever mentioned and now the question is fine.