# DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=66

Tags: java, certificate, keystore, pkcs#12

I have the following issue when I try to load a certificate :

```
> java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=66, too big.
|   at sun.security.util.DerInputStream.getLength(DerInputStream.java:561)
|   at sun.security.util.DerValue.init(DerValue.java:365)
|   at sun.security.util.DerValue.<init>(DerValue.java:320)
|   at sun.security.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore.engineLoad(PKCS12KeyStore.java:1914)
|   at java.security.KeyStore.load(KeyStore.java:1445)
|   at com.sequenceiq.cloudbreak.cloud.wap.client.WapClient.getFactory(WapClient.java:61)
|   at com.sequenceiq.cloudbreak.cloud.wap.client.WapClient.checkConnect(WapClient.java:80)
|   at com.sequenceiq.cloudbreak.cloud.wap.WapCredentialConnector.verify(WapCredentialConnector.java:53)
|   at com.sequenceiq.cloudbreak.cloud.handler.CredentialVerificationHandler.accept(CredentialVerificationHandler.java:43)
|   at com.sequenceiq.cloudbreak.cloud.handler.CredentialVerificationHandler.accept(CredentialVerificationHandler.java:20)
|   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
|   at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
|   at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
|   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
|   at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:302)
|   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:190)
|   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:157)
|   at org.springframework.aop.framework.adapter.MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.invoke(MethodBeforeAdviceInterceptor.java:52)
|   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
|   at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:92)
|   at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:179)
|   at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:208)
|   at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy201.accept(Unknown Source)
|   at reactor.bus.EventBus$3.accept(EventBus.java:317)
|   at reactor.bus.EventBus$3.accept(EventBus.java:310)
|   at reactor.bus.routing.ConsumerFilteringRouter.route(ConsumerFilteringRouter.java:72)
|2016-06-07 19:56:59,465 [reactorDispatcher-17] accept:56 [34mINFO [0;39m c.s.c.c.h.CredentialVerificationHandler - [owner:c90f9d2e-587f-4af6-a3a8-f1d321caa3a1] [type:springLog] [id:null] [name:debug2] Credential verification successfully finished
|   at reactor.bus.routing.TraceableDelegatingRouter.route(TraceableDelegatingRouter.java:51)
|   at reactor.bus.EventBus.accept(EventBus.java:591)
|   at reactor.bus.EventBus.accept(EventBus.java:63)
|   at reactor.core.dispatch.AbstractLifecycleDispatcher.route(AbstractLifecycleDispatcher.java:160)
web01#3|2016-06-07 19:56:59,466 [http-nio-9091-exec-4] init:51 [34mINFO [0;39m c.s.c.s.s.c.a.ServiceProviderCredentialAdapter - [owner:c90f9d2e-587f-4af6-a3a8-f1d321caa3a1] [type:springLog] [id:] [name:] Result: CloudPlatformResult{status=OK, statusReason='null', errorDetails=null, request=CloudPlatformRequest{cloudContext=CloudContext{id=null, name='debug2', platform='StringType{value='WAP'}', owner='c90f9d2e-587f-4af6-a3a8-f1d321caa3a1'}, cloudCredential=com.sequenceiq.cloudbreak.cloud.model.CloudCredential@4bd64260}}
|   at reactor.core.dispatch.MultiThreadDispatcher$MultiThreadTask.run(MultiThreadDispatcher.java:74)
|   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
|   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
|   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Here is the code sample :

```
          keyInput = new FileInputStream(pKeyFile);
          keyStore.load(keyInput, pKeyPassword.toCharArray());
          keyInput.close();
```

Note that before loading it, I write the certificate that the server received in a new file :

```
        File file = new File(name);
        try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(file)){
            fw.write(certificate);
        }catch(IOException e){
            LOGGER.debug("Writer issue",e);
        }
```

I already tried to read the file after writing it and it works. So I am quite sure it is not a InputStream issue.

The certificate is a pkcs12 file.
Could it be that I can't load a certificate that I just write in a new file ?

Comment: Are you calling fw.flush() or fw.close() after writing to the file?

Comment: Yes, it is hidden in the try with resource http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/try-with-resources.html

Comment: Ok, I think more context is needed about the files you are saving and loading. keystore.load() would expect input file in JKS format, is that what you are trying to load?

Comment: The file I am writing is a pkcs12 file.
Then I try to load it as a certificate with keyStore load. 
Note that keystore work with pkcs12 format, I try it with a another file that was already present in my machine and it works

Comment: You can only load keystore from JKS file. Usually one would import pkcs12 file into keystore using keytool application, supplied with JDK. See for example: http://www.webfarmr.eu/2010/04/import-pkcs12-private-keys-into-jks-keystores-using-java-keytool/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12618690/how-to-use-certificates-from-a-java-pkcs12-keystore-for-encrypting-and-decrypti. That what I use and it works with a file already present locally.

Answer (score 1):

PKCS#12 is encoded in DER format, and DER format is binary .

You are using a FileReader that is (from javadoc)

> Convenience class for writing character files.

which inherites from OutputStreamWriter

> An OutputStreamWriter is a bridge from character streams to byte streams: Characters written to it are encoded into bytes using a specified charset.

Therefore

1. You have an encoding problem converting binary to char
2. The file you receive is not really in binary format. It could be in Base64

In both cases, use a `FileOutputStream.write` or `Files.write` to store the file, and if your 'certificate' variable is a String, first convert it to binary

```
File file = new File(name);
FileOutputStream fout = new FileOutputStream(file);
fout.write (data);

Files.write(Paths.get("name"), data);
```

Comment: I changed to :

        try(FileOutputStream fw = new FileOutputStream(file)){
         fw.write(certificate.getBytes());
        }catch(IOException e){
         LOGGER.debug("Writer issue",e);
        }


and I get the same error as before.

Comment: What kind of variable is 'certificate'? How have you read it ? The problem could be there. You should have a `byte[]` not a `String`  Have you checked if the data is really in binary format?

Comment: I think it is binary : \Q?ÆØ?zv$ÁdùQC¥¹ºÃH (it looks like that when I print it). Certificate is a string.

Comment: It is binary, so it should not be in a String. Please, set extension of saved file to .p12 and double click on your computer to see if OS can open it. If you are not a windows user, encode the data in base64 and insert it in this page: https://lapo.it/asn1js/ . If the OS opens the file or the page decodes the content, then the file is OK, else the file is bad saved, or it is not a pcks12, or you have some extra characters added in some way

Comment: I can open it with Windows. The thing is that I am passing it from client side to server side as a string. So that's why I have a string. Do you think I should do something client side to passe it as byte[] ?

Comment: You should read the content as byte[], and be aware how it is sent to server. If you use `application/octet-stream` then you can send bytes. If you use `application/json` or `application/xml`, you have to send text, so in this case is necessary to convert byte[] to String, and in server part from String to byte[]. Because you can not convert directly from byte[] to String, usually is used Base64 format. For example  `DataTypeConverter.printBase64Binary`. But if you use some library like JAXB to encode XML or JSON, it does the work for you, converting automatically byte[] to String

Comment: But, if the you can open the saved filte, it means that the file was sent successfully (you could have problems later). Therefore, it could be an streams problem. Ensure you have close and flush everything.

Comment: Quite sure I have close everything, I already tried to read the file and close it before loading it in keystore and it worked.

Comment: therefore, what is the current status? I am not sure. It is weird that you can read the pkcs12 file directly, but was not possible if it has been uploaded