# Error in openshift " java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=66, too big " while using .pfx certificate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, openshift

I have one certificate which is required to connect to external site. This works fine in my local windows system. But when i deploy the application to openshift, i get this error

java.io.IOException: DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=66, too big.

certificate is in .pfx and in encoded format.
What can i do to make it work in Openshift? Is it because of the Linux env thats causing the issue?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DerInputStream.getLength(): lengthTag=66](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37939592/derinputstream-getlength-lengthtag-66)

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same issue and the way I fixed it is by simply changing the certificate extension from `.pfx` to `.p12`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).